# Int overflow in Java

Tags: java

Suppose, I have a simple method:

```
public int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

If I run it with max int values

```
add(2147483647, 2147483647);
```

I get `-2`. I found that if we overflow int then we go to min integer value (`-2147483648`) and keep adding.

Let's do some math. If I add `2147483647 + 2147483647` I should get -1, because

```
-2147483648 + 2147483647 = -1
```

So why do I get `-2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it like this:

```
  2147483647 + 2147483647
= 2147483647 + ( 1 + 2147483646 )
= ( 2147483647 + 1 ) + 2147483646
= -2147483648 + 2147483646  // Because of overflow
= -2
```

That is, to get the lefthand 2147483647 to overflow, you had to add 1 to it. That 1 came from the right-hand 2147483647, so now there is only 2147483646 left.

Of course, internally it's done by 2s-complement addition, not by adding 1s until you reach the end. The above just clarifies the maths.

Answer (score 5):

Lets do some math. Max is `2147483647` but min is `-2147483648`.

```
2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648
2147483647 + 2 = -2147483647
...
2147483647 + n = -2147483648 + n - 1
```

which for `n` = `2147483647` gives us

```
2147483647 + 2147483647 = -2147483648 + 2147483647 - 1 = -1 - 1 = -2
```