# To find smallest word in a string in java

Tags: java, string

This is the code that i have written for finding the smallest word in a string but whenever i try to run it in eclipse it shows me an (String index out of range -2147483648) error in nested while statement, that i had marked , i do not understand the cause of it since my program seems to be running well in the range i.e less than length of the input string.

Thanks in advance!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Minword {
    public static String minLengthWord(String input){

        // Write your code here
        int count[]=new int[50],i,j=0,len=input.length();
        String output = "";
        for(i=0;i<len;i++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i)!=' ')
            {
                count[j]++;
            }
            else
                j++;
        }
        int minidx=0;
        for(i=1;i<j;i++)
        {
            if(count[minidx]>count[i])
                minidx=i;
        }
        int words=0;
        i=0;
        while(words<=minidx)
        {

            if(words==minidx)
            {
                ***while(i<len && input.charAt(i)!=' ')***
                {
                    output+=input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else if(i<len && input.charAt(i)==' ')
                   words++;
            i++;
        }

        return output;


    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input,output;
        input=s.nextLine();
        output=minLengthWord(input);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your outer `while` loop is infinite, because `words` doesn't get incremented under certain conditions.

Comment: your outer while loop is always true, i increases till reaches the maximum integer value. see my answer in details

Answer (score 1):

I have problems following your code, but to get the shortest word's length, you can use a Stream and `min()`. Your minLengthWord method could be like:

```
String f = "haha hah ha jajaja";
OptionalInt shortest = Arrays.stream(f.split(" ")).mapToInt(String::length).min();
System.out.println(shortest.getAsInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `i`, which is a `signed int`, so it ranges from -2147483648 to 2147483647. 
The following case shows your problem:

```
i = 2147483647;
i++;
```

After the increment, `i`'s value will be -2147483648 due to a int overflow. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32539712/int-overflow-in-java).

It seems you are getting a huge input, thus it is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, -2147483648 is the maximal integer + 1. You have a wrap around. The variable i got so big that it start on the negative side again.

You have to use a long if you want to process texts that are larger than 2 GB.

Comment: The text isn't larger than 2 GB.  You can input the phrase "Hello World" and it still happens.

Comment: the reason is the outer loop is always true and variable i increases to maximum

Answer (score 0):

```
       while(words<=minidx)
        {

            if(words==minidx)
            {
                ***while(i<len && input.charAt(i)!=' ')***
                {
                    output+=input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            else if(i<len && input.charAt(i)==' ')
                   words++;
            i++;
        }
```

**Your problem is you when words and minidx are both 0,  your outer while loop is always true and words are always equal to minidx, and i keeps increasing until reaches its maximum number.**

you need to add `break` after your inner while loop and secondly, you need to change `i<j` to `i<=j`

Below is the corrected code:

```
   int minidx = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= j; i++) {  //-------------------------> change i<j to i<=j
            if (count[minidx] > count[i])
                minidx = i;
        }
        int words = 0;
        i = 0;

        System.out.println(minidx);
        while (words <= minidx) {

            if (words == minidx) {
                while (i < len && input.charAt(i) != ' ') {
                    output += input.charAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
                break;  //-------------------------> add break statement here.
            } else if (i < len && input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                words++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I tried running your code with an input of "Hello World", `minidx` was 0 before the `while` loop.  `words` is also 0, so `words<=minidx` is true and the loop is entered.  `words==minidx` is true (they're both 0), so the `if` statement is entered.  Because it never enters the `else if` (which is the only place `words` is changed), `words` is always 0.  So the loop becomes an infinite loop.  In the meantime, `i` just keeps growing, until it overflows and becomes negative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that makes use of Java 8's Stream API:
Remove all your code from minLengthWord Method and paste below code it will work and resolve your runtime issue too

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));

String shortestWord = words.stream().min(
                                     Comparator.comparing(
                                     word -> word.length()))
                                    .get();

System.out.println(shortestWord);
```